# WPF datagrid selected row and binding event to it

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I have a DataGrid with some rows, and now when I select one row I want to simultaneously fire up event with this selection, but I am having a problem.

This is my user control resources:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CollapsedRow" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">

            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="OnGroupChange" />

            <Setter Property="DetailsVisibility" Value="Collapsed" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DodgerBlue" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="SteelBlue"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources
```

And my datagrid xaml is simple:

```
<DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource CollapsedRow}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CanUserAddRows="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Applications}" >
```

Well as you see I have a event setter for one mouse click that will fire up event and trigger that will change background colour of row if is selected. But it works like first you need to select row that one click and then fire event that is second click. is there a way to do it with one click?

Comment: did you try with PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MouseLeftButtonDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown?view=netframework-4.7.2) event gets fired before the selection of the row gets changed. This means the property `IsSelected` of your row will be `false`. You could use the [Selected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.selected?view=netframework-4.7.2) event which gets fired after the selection was changed. Just add a new handler like

```
<EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="OnSelected"/>
```

and

```
private void OnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Column selection change, IsSelected = " + ((DataGridRow)sender).IsSelected);
}
```